# GameCenter orientation lock in landscape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, game-center

When GameCenter is loaded, it is in default portrait view.

Is there anyways to load and lock it in landscape view like fruit ninja did?

Thanks..

I'm using it with cocos2d..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using auto-rotation at all?  The default I believe is UIViewRotation, which for me doesn't work at all (how did you get it to successfully work in portrait?).  If you change to CCDirector rotation, it should work.  You can modify this in GameConfig.h

Comment: yes.. it is auto rotation... GameConfig.h? i cant find it.. is it in gamekit framework??

Comment: kind of works.. but when player hold it in portrait mode and press gamecenter, the gamecenter appears in portrait again... =(

Comment: solved!!! upgrade to 0.99.5 and my codes:
GKMatchmakerViewController* mmvc = [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:_tmpView.view];
[_tmpView presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:NO];

// add this
 mmvc.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS( 90.0f ) );
 mmvc.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);

Answer (score 0):

i think method

```
[self presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES];
```

will help u.
Hope it help =))